# Registering User using Smack 4.1.3

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

We are building a chat client in java and using smack 4.1.3. What I noticed is there is huge change in smack APIs after smack 4.0 and registrations examples available on the internet are not working for smack 4.1.3. I am not getting write APIs to register user. May anybody give sample codes.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

This connects ejabberd server with smack 4.1.3.

```
   XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setUsernameAndPassword("testuser", "pass")
            .setServiceName("example.com")
            .setHost("example.com")
            .setResource("test")
            .setSecurityMode(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
            .setPort(5222)
            .build();

    SASLMechanism mechanism = new SASLDigestMD5Mechanism();
    SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism(mechanism);
    SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("SCRAM-SHA-1");
    SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");

    AbstractXMPPConnection con = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
    try {
        con.connect();
        con.login();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getCause() + " " + ex.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(redcore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }
```

Comment: Hi spali, thanks a lot for this reply. Do you know code changes that we need to do if we are using bosh mode and not tcp mode. What we feel is bosh mode more suitable than tcp mode in our case.

Comment: Check this code, this may be helpful .           https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/src-html/org/jivesoftware/smack/bosh/XMPPBOSHConnection.html#line.129

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any problem or restriction that you are not allowed to user simple REST api's, plugins provided by openfire for registering user's, retrieving, deleting etc.

Refer [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html) for the official docs.